# How to make a div a complete circle in a grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Actually I have three divs `(.box, .rating-options, .rating)`. I wanted to create a layout like this:

[image: I wanted to create a layout like this]

However I'm not getting a complete circle, they're ovals. The width of the parent element is fixed (i.e. 25%), so in order to get a complete circle, I have to adjust the height of `.rating-options`, but that too gets distorted when it is responsive.

[image]

```css
:root{
    --dark-blue: hsl(213, 19%, 18%);
}
.box{
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);
    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.rating-options{
    display: grid;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
.rating{
    background-color:hsla(217, 12%, 63%, 0.123);
    margin-left: 1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="rating-options">
      <div id="1" class="rating">1</div>
      <div id="2" class="rating">2</div>
      <div id="3" class="rating">3</div>
      <div id="4" class="rating">4</div>
      <div id="5" class="rating">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root{
    --dark-blue: hsl(213, 19%, 18%);
}
.box{
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);
    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.rating-options{
    display: grid;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
.rating{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:hsla(217, 12%, 63%, 0.123);
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;


}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="rating-options">
      <div id="1" class="rating">1</div>
      <div id="2" class="rating">2</div>
      <div id="3" class="rating">3</div>
      <div id="4" class="rating">4</div>
      <div id="5" class="rating">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you closer to what you want, but I've set a min-width on the container, as it's eventually going to get distorted no matter what you do, so I'd rethink the `width: 25%` — at least via media queries for smaller screens.

```css
:root{
    --dark-blue: hsl(213, 19%, 18%);
}
.box{
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);
    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 1rem;
    min-width: 300px;
}
.rating-options {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    gap: 1rem;
}
.rating-options div {
    background-color:hsla(217, 12%, 63%, 0.123);
    border-radius: 50%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="rating-options">
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
    <div id="3">3</div>
    <div id="4">4</div>
    <div id="5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```